# Determine the equilibrium points (stationary) and sketch the trajectories.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, systems-of-equations

Consider the system of ODE'S in the plan
$$x_1 '=x_2(x_{2}^2-x_1^2)$$
$$x_2 '=-x_1(x_{2}^2-x_1^2)$$

Determine the equilibrium points (stationary) and sketch the trajectories.

I tried to find system solutions
$$x_2(x_{2}^2-x_1^2)=0$$
$$-x_1(x_{2}^2-x_1^2)=0$$
So we have to
$$x_2(x_{2}^2-x_1^2)-x_1(x_{2}^2-x_1^2)=(x_2^2-x_1^2)(x_2-x_1)=(x_2-x_1)^2(x_2+x_1)$$

So,$(x_2+x_1)=0$ or $(x^2-x_1)^2=0$.Hence, the equilibrium points are on line $(x_1(t)=t,x_2(t)=-t)$ and line $(x_1(t)=t,x_2(t)=t)$.

Is correct?

How to descend the direction of the trajectories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the equilibrium points

$$(x_1, x_2) = (0, 0) ~~~\mbox{and}~~~ x_2 = \pm x_1$$

So, we see we have the origin and two lines as critical points.

Drawing the phase portrait

[image]

We can also add the critical points to the phase portrait

[image]

Comment: how to calculate this?

Comment: Looking at the equations, we can see that $(0,0)$ is a critical point. For the others, we have $$x_2^2 = x_1^2 \implies x_2 = \pm x_1$$ Clear?

Comment: yes, but what about the directions of the trajectories?

Comment: Write $\dfrac{x_2'}{x_1'} = ...$ and then look at the sign of the slope in the different regions.

Comment: alright, i'll try! Thanks